# Boundary Java regex does not work

Tags: java, regex, boundary

Could you please tell me why this expression does not return `TRUE`?

```
public class test  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String str = "The dog plays";
    boolean t = str.matches("\\bdog\\b");

    System.out.println(t);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`matches` method will always try to match the whole string. It won't be a suitable method for matching a particular string. So change your regex to,

```
".*\\bdog\\b.*"
```

in-order to make the matches method to return true.

```
String str = "dog plays";
System.out.println(str.matches(".*\\bdog\\b.*"));
```

Output:

```
true
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. Note that the above regex will match also the string `foo:dog:bar`. If you want the dog to be a separate word , i suggest you to use this regex.

```
".*(?<!\\S)dog(?!\\S).*"
```

**Example:**

```
System.out.println("dog plays".matches(".*(?<!\\S)dog(?!\\S).*"));
System.out.println("foo:dog:bar".matches(".*(?<!\\S)dog(?!\\S).*"));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: @Rahul it should match. Can you please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Matcher`class:

- `matches()` returns true if the entire string matches the expression
- `find()` returns true if any subsequence of the string matches the expression.

So it's likely that this is what you want:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "The dog plays";
        boolean t = str.find("\\bdog\\b");

        System.out.println(t);

    }
}
```